# LVL Returns unlicensed on phone startup

Tags: android, android-lvl

I have implemented Google's LVL (License Verification Library) into my live wallpapers recently.

It works perfectly fine if the phone is running, but if the wallpaper is chosen and the phone is restarted the LVL returns false until the user chooses another wallpaper, then mine again. Is there a way around this other than having to continually check while it returns false?

Comment: As a side note: the best practice IMO is checking license only once when app is first opened, instead of checking it every time user open your app, which is not necessary.